# Unable to determine the principal end of the 'MyApp.Data.AAA_BBB' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables

```sql
create table AAA ( AAAKey int primary key, .... )
create table BBB (
  AAAKey int references AAA(AAAKey), -- Foreign key to AAA
  X      int references X  (XKey),
  ....
  primary key (AAA, X))
```

And in C#, the classes generated by EF 6.1.3

```
[Table("dbo.AAA")]
public partial class AAA
{
  public AAA() { BBB = new HashSet<BBB>(); }
  [Key] public int AAAKey { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<BBB> BBB { get; set; }
}
[Table("dbo.BBB")]
public partial class BBB
{
  [Key] public int AAAKey { get; set; }
  [Key] public int XKey { get; set; }
  public virtual AAA AAA { get; set; }
}
......
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder medelBuilder)
{
  ....
     modelBuilder.Entity<AAA>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BBB)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AAA)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.AAAKey)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

However, the code raise the execption when running `SaveChanges()`?

**Update:**
The issue is strange that it only occurs for some data. And I sort of find a solution by converting my original `foreach (...) {...}; SaveChange()` to `foreach (.....) { .....; SaveChange(); }`. Does it sound a bug of EF? BTW, all the data I tested always have the duplicate key insertion exceptions, which are expected.

Answer (score 0):

You meant `AAAKey` to be a foreign key right?

```
public partial class BBB
{
  [ForeignKey("AAA")]
  public int AAAKey { get; set; }
  public virtual AAA AAA { get; set; }
  // other stuff...
}
```

Comment: I got the following error after add the FK attriubute. `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The property 'AAAKey' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9  I just copied all your code, fixed the compliation issues, and added `ForeignKey`, and working on my machine, so I suspect that the problem lies in some code that you haven't posted yet.  Try to create a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post it so that we can help you find your real problem.

Comment: Please see the **Update** in the question. That exception happens only to some inputs.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9  Even then, It's hard to say what the problem is if I don't have an SSCCE, and sample input to play around with.